# How to set some alarms using AlarmManager?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm making Alarm Application for Android. I wanna set more alarms using AlarmManager. How can I do it? As far as I know, I need to use PendingIntent with different request code to set some alarms. I was trying to increment a static variable and I did it but if user reload the application the variable has request code as zero. How can I set some alarms even after a reloading my application?

I have one activity

```
public class NewAlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Calendar calendar;

private static int REQUEST_CODE_ALARM = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_alarm);

    showTimePickerDialog();

    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fb_save_alarm);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveAlarm();
        }
    });
}

// set time for an alarm
private void showTimePickerDialog() {
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(NewAlarmActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        }
    }, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.MINUTE, true);

    timePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    timePickerDialog.show();
}

// get full time like a '05:45'
private String getFullTime(int hour, int minute) {
    String h = String.valueOf(hour);
    String m = String.valueOf(minute);

    if (hour < 10) h = "0" + hour;
    if (minute < 10) m = "0" + minute;

    return h + ":" + m;
}

private void saveAlarm() {
    setAlarm();
    insertIntoSQLite();
    finish();
}

private void setAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewAlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), ++REQUEST_CODE_ALARM, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}

private void insertIntoSQLite() {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(NewAlarmActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("time", getFullTime(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
    contentValues.put("description", et_description.getText().toString());

    database.insert("alarm", null, contentValues);

    dbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code. what you have done so for.

Comment: @Raza check out

Comment: the problem you are facing is that your request code is always initialized to 0 whenever you launch the app. in order to get the previous code after setting the alarm, the incremented request code should be stored in persistent memory. either shared preferences or sqlite. and again get that request code inside onCreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save small data to sharedPreference.
To save your *REQUEST_CODE_ALARM* value do this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("Request_code", REQUEST_CODE_ALARM);
editor.apply()
```

To retrieve it

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
int Request_code = prefs.getInt("REQUEST_CODE_ALARM", 0); //0 is the default value.
```

I dont suggest you to use SQL database for this purpose because SharedPreferences are useful for storing user preferences, where there are just a handful of variables that need storing. SQLite on the other hand would be better for storing data where there is a large set of items, such as song titles in a music library which need to be searched through.

Answer (score 0):

Alarm manager will not be exact above api 19. 
Try using Workmanager.